# Order by delivers an unexpected order of results

Tags: sql

My query is:

```
SELECT id, name, total FROM <table> order by total
```

This results in the following table:

```
id |  name | total
1  |  Amy  |   
2  |  Xin  |
3  |  Ray  | 13
4  |  Aly  | 7
5  |  Shy  | 3
```

The first 2 records return a NULL in the total column. How should i change my order by to make the "total" column descending with the NULL values below the numeric values?

Comment: Ive made an edit, i meant order by not group by.

Comment: Is this your real query? I doubt this query can produce those results.

Comment: It is a simplified example of the result that my big query returns.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: `order by total nulls last`

Comment: Thanks guys! That helped me out it works.